# Ошибка реализации алгоритма игры в города

Tags: python, алгоритм

Необходимо решить задачу по "игре в города", т.е входные данные это слова на латинице, например, `"aab", "aac", "baas"`, соответственно ответ будет `"aab","baas","aac"`. На небольшом количестве слов отрабатывает нормально, но при инпуте ~900 слов зацикливается бесконечно в части:

```
for j in range(0,N-U):
    if (s[j][0] == words[i][-1]):
       searchNextWord(s,j,U)
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема.. хотелось бы получить совет.

Весь код:

```
 def searchNextWord(words,i,U):
        global Result
        s = [None]*N
        if (Result==True):
            return
        res[U] = words[i]
        U += 1
        if (U == N):
            Result = res[U - 1] == words[i]
        if (Result==True):
            return

        for j in range(0,N-U):
            if (j<i):
                s[j]=words[j]
            else:
                s[j]=words[j+1]

        for j in range(0,N-U):
            if (s[j][0] == words[i][-1]):
                searchNextWord(s,j,U)


    words=[]
    N=int(input())
    if (N<1 or N>1000):
        exit()
    for i in range(N):
        new_element = str(input())
        words.append(new_element)

    res = [None]*N
    for i in words:
        if (len(i)>10):
            exit()

    Result = False
    for i in range(0,N):
        if (Result==False):
            searchNextWord(words, i, 0)

    if (Result==True):
        for i in range(0,N):
            print(res[i])
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Comment: Если на небольшом количестве данных работает правильно, то ошибки в алгоритме нет. А что зацикливается, так это кажется. Подождите час-два, может быть, день, рекурсия отработает и будет результат.

Comment: игра в города, как я помню - вспомнить город начинающийся на букву, которой закончился предыдущий город. Вы хотите построить такую цепочку из слов? Из вопроса это не понятно

Comment: Да, всё верно. Даны слова и из них нужно построить цепочку по принцицу игры в города.
Если алгоритм работает на небольших значениях это не значит что он корректен. Видимо возникает ситуация в которой он уходит в бесконечный цикл. Потому что он сортирует условно 900/1000 слов за долю секунды и потом начинает крутить бесконечно.

Answer (score 1):

Для ускорения Вашего алгоритма модно рассмотреть два пути:

- как альтернативу рекурсии можно попробовать использовать итеративный подход со стеком:

  ```
   stack = [(start_state)]
   while stack:
       current_state = stack.pop()
       # process this state
       # if conditions of the final result are true for the state 
       # then add result of the state into final data structure
       for child_state in current_state: # processed state
           stack.append(child_state)
  ```
- в качестве словаря для городов можно воспользоваться префиксным деревом, в котором ответ для следующего города будет находиться как раз в корне этого дерева:

  ```
   # root = prefix tree with cities
   # last_city = results[-1]
   if last_city[-1] in root:
       # random choice of the next node until we reach the trie leaf
       # then mark this leaf as `used`
  ```